# how to keep calling a backend api until i receive the 200 ok in the response

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rxjs, observable

I am developing an angular project, I need to call a backend api, if it's not return 200, then i need to call this api every 30 seconds, until I get 200 OK.

I am using angular, the format I usually call an backend api is this:

```
this.productServices.onProductBuy(product_id).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response)
});
```

`onProductBuy()` contains some calling api code, it's just simply a get request

If a HTTP 200 is not received for this onProdcutBuy api, I need to call this api one more time until I get the 200.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
this.productServices.onProductBuy(product_id).pipe(
  retry({
    delay: 30 * 1000
  } as any)
).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response)
});
```

This retry an infinite amount of times and also add a delay of 30 second. The type definition of `retry` seems to be broken with the version I am using. That's why I had to use `as any`.

But the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/retry.ts) shows, that `retry` accepts an object with a delay property:

```
export interface RetryConfig {
  /**
   * The maximum number of times to retry. If `count` is omitted, `retry` will try to
   * resubscribe on errors infinite number of times.
   */
  count?: number;
  /**
   * The number of milliseconds to delay before retrying, OR a function to
   * return a notifier for delaying. If a function is given, that function should
   * return a notifier that, when it emits will retry the source. If the notifier
   * completes _without_ emitting, the resulting observable will complete without error,
   * if the notifier errors, the error will be pushed to the result.
   */
  delay?: number | ((error: any, retryCount: number) => ObservableInput<any>);
  /**
   * Whether or not to reset the retry counter when the retried subscription
   * emits its first value.
   */
  resetOnSuccess?: boolean;
}

export function retry<T>(count?: number): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
export function retry<T>(config: RetryConfig): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rxjs retry](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retry):

```
this.productServices.onProductBuy(product_id)
  .pipe(retry(2)) // <-- Here
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response)
  });
```

With the above it will retry twice. If you'd like to retry forever, just don't add a number to it, it will keep retrying until a success is received:

```
this.productServices.onProductBuy(product_id)
  .pipe(retry()) // <-- Here
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response)
  });
```

Don't forget to avoid the [memory leak trap](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433) with subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, one more question, I want to stop retry when this api return 200 OK as status code. how do I do that?

Comment: add `take(1)` to the pipe, after the retry and the observable will close when there is a success

Answer (score 0):

Alright!

So personally, I believe this should be handled by the backend framework. However if you really want to achieve this on the angular side of the application, here is my solution of the problem ( Obviously without using retry as that can sometime be problematic as other mentioned already ) :

1. Define a Subject in ProductService Class as below :

   public onProductBySubject = new Subject();
2. Define a method in component.ts file ( if not defined already ) to perform the invocation of the required method from the service class :

   public justAnExample() {
   this.productServices.onProductBuy(product_id).subscribe(response => {

   if(response.code != 200){
   setTimeOut(this.productServices.onProductBySubject.next(true),30000);
   }
   console.log(response)
   });
   }
3. In the ngOnInit() life cycle hook function , make a subscription :

   this.mysubscription = this.productServices.onProductBySubject.subscribe(value=>{
   if(value) this.justAnExample();
   });
4. in ngDestroy() life cycle hook function, unsubscribe 'mysubscription'.

Let me know if this will help and upvote my answer so that it will help others.